# XPath/Javascript - INVALID_STATE_ERR when creating new nodes tree

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

I'm currently playing arround with JS and the embedded XPath. I'm trying to create a little test script and found an interesting error which I'd like to understand. I'm calling the evaluate function like this:

```
var result = document.evaluate(
    xpath,
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ANY_TYPE);
```

In this case I get mixed results. The string, boolean and number types are no problem to handle but the UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE is somehow tricky.

My function to handle the result looks like that:

```
    function nodes(iterator, parentNode) {
        var cur = iterator.iterateNext(); // do not touch! altering this object causes a INVALID_STATE_ERR Exception
        var myObj = cur == null || cur == undefined ? undefined : cur.cloneNode(true);
        var count = 0;

        while(myObj) {
            parentNode.appendChild(myObj);
            var =  iterator.iterateNext().cloneNode(true);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to run this function I get an  INVALID_STATE_ERR exception. But why? I do clone the objects and my parent node is a new created element node. (document.createElement('body') which should replace the original body node at the end.

Do I need to create the new-body element in another way? Is this exception threwn because the new body element is attached to the current document tree? How could I do it if I can't use createElement?

Comment: Consider to post enough sample code allowing us to reproduce the problem, perhaps using a site like http://jsfiddle.net/. I am afraid a line like `var =  iterator.iterateNext().cloneNode(true);` is not even syntactically correct. As for the XPath DOM API, consider to first iterate over the result to collect the nodes found, for instance in an array, then to manipulate the DOM tree. On the other hand a HTML document has exactly one `body` element, so why do you need to use an iterator? Shouldn't selecting a single node suffice?

Comment: I tried to morph your snippets into a test case to reproduce the issue, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/pe95g/2/. I think that example should work fine and it indeed does so in Mozilla and Opera, yet in Chrome and Safari I get an "INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11". In my understanding that is a bug in WebKit's DOM implementation although the DOM Level 3 XPath note is not particularly detailed as to what is a "document modification" that "invalidates the iteration". If I change the code to use a snapshot (http://jsfiddle.net/WT5Uk/1/) it works fine with Mozilla, Opera, Safari, Chrome.

Comment: You're right. I also tried this with snapshot but there I found another strange failure. When I use the evaluate function I use the definied function "evaluate( xpathExpression, contextNode, namespaceResolver, resultType, result );" in firefox but the same calling style leads to errors in chrome (15.0.874.106). There I have to call like that: "document.evaluate( xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE)" Strange! But you're right the very same code from above runs in Firefox 7. (If you add your comment as answer I'll accept it because it helped me a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make a test case to reproduce the issue, http://jsfiddle.net/pe95g/2/. It works fine with Mozilla and Opera but fails with WebKit browsers like Chrome and Safari. In my view it should not fail as the DOM document that is being queried is not changed, only nodes not attached to that document are created and changed while the XPath iteration happens. On the other hand the W3C DOM Level 3 XPath note is not very precise as to what is a "document modification" that "invalidates the iteration".

As a workaround I tried to use a snapshot instead of an iterator with the DOM Level 3 XPath API, http://jsfiddle.net/WT5Uk/1/, that approach works fine for me with all four major desktop browser supporting `document.evaluate` (i.e. Mozilla, Opera, Safari, Chrome). So that is the only workaround that I can suggest.